# Split an XML Node based on certain condition

Tags: java, xml-parsing

My Source XML Looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MT_A2B>
    <Header>
        <ReceiverID>XYZ Pvt Ltd.</ReceiverID>
        <Date>2013-05-16</Date>
        <FileId>1</FileId>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </Header>
    <Invoice>
        <ItemsInfo>
            <Item id="A1">
                <AccountID>1234567890</AccountID>
                <AccountName>657-6746-AM2</AccountName>
                <AccountType>CONTRACT</AccountType>
                <Type>/item/cxn/vpn/cycle</Type>
                <Name>VPN cycle fees</Name>
                <SessionCount>3</SessionCount>
                <NetAmount>3000.00</NetAmount>
                <Tot>
                    <UsageClass>AOC</UsageClass>
                    <SessionCount>3</SessionCount>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <FreeQuantity>1</FreeQuantity>
                    <NetAmount>3000.00</NetAmount>
                    <ZoneTot>
                        <ZoneDescription>To Category 2</ZoneDescription>
                        <GLID>300|A1000001|F1000001|50001</GLID>
                        <SetUpFee>0.00000</SetUpFee>
                        <Unit>1</Unit>
                        <UnitPrice>1000.0000</UnitPrice>
                        <SessionCount>2</SessionCount>
                        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                        <FreeQuantity>1</FreeQuantity>
                        <NetAmount>2000.00</NetAmount>
                    </ZoneTot>
                    <ZoneTot>
                        <ZoneDescription>To Category 2</ZoneDescription>
                        <GLID>300|A1000001|F1000001|50001</GLID>
                        <SetUpFee>0.00000</SetUpFee>
                        <Unit>1</Unit>
                        <UnitPrice>1000.0000</UnitPrice>
                        <SessionCount>1</SessionCount>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <FreeQuantity>0</FreeQuantity>
                        <NetAmount>1000.00</NetAmount>
                    </ZoneTot>
                </Tot>
            </Item>
        </ItemsInfo>
    </Invoice>
</MT_A2B>
```

I have to Check if the Tot Node has more than one ZoneTot. If Yes, then I have to create one more Tot Node to accommodate the second ZoneTot Node. Basically, Each Tot Node should have only one ZoneTot node. If there is more than one ZoneTot node in Tot node then I have to format it properly. I need to do some calculations for the fields present in second Tot node but I have not mentioned it here. I have to first fulfill my basic requirement of formatting the XML.

I wish to have the output XML Look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MT_A2B>
    <Header>
        <ReceiverID>XYZ Pvt Ltd.</ReceiverID>
        <Date>2013-05-16</Date>
        <FileId>1</FileId>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </Header>
    <Invoice>
        <ItemsInfo>
            <Item id="A1">
                <AccountID>1234567890</AccountID>
                <AccountName>657-6746-AM2</AccountName>
                <AccountType>CONTRACT</AccountType>
                <Type>/item/cxn/vpn/cycle</Type>
                <Name>VPN cycle fees</Name>
                <SessionCount>3</SessionCount>
                <NetAmount>3000.00</NetAmount>
                <Tot>
                    <UsageClass>AOC</UsageClass>
                    <SessionCount>3</SessionCount>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <FreeQuantity>1</FreeQuantity>
                    <NetAmount>3000.00</NetAmount>
                    <ZoneTot>
                        <ZoneDescription>To Category 2</ZoneDescription>
                        <GLID>300|A1000001|F1000001|50001</GLID>
                        <SetUpFee>0.00000</SetUpFee>
                        <Unit>1</Unit>
                        <UnitPrice>1000.0000</UnitPrice>
                        <SessionCount>2</SessionCount>
                        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                        <FreeQuantity>1</FreeQuantity>
                        <NetAmount>2000.00</NetAmount>
                    </ZoneTot>
                </Tot>

                <Tot>
                    <UsageClass>AOC</UsageClass>
                    <SessionCount>3</SessionCount>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <FreeQuantity>1</FreeQuantity>
                    <NetAmount>3000.00</NetAmount>
                    <ZoneTot>
                        <ZoneDescription>To Category 2</ZoneDescription>
                        <GLID>300|A1000001|F1000001|50001</GLID>
                        <SetUpFee>0.00000</SetUpFee>
                        <Unit>1</Unit>
                        <UnitPrice>1000.0000</UnitPrice>
                        <SessionCount>1</SessionCount>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <FreeQuantity>0</FreeQuantity>
                        <NetAmount>1000.00</NetAmount>
                    </ZoneTot>
                </Tot>
            </Item>
        </ItemsInfo>
    </Invoice>
</MT_A2B>
```

Comment: Rather than pasting large XML documents, perhaps you could cut down the question to show just the essentials?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post some code you have for this and explain what's missing?

Comment: Hi @Taylor, <br/>I have tried two ways of parsing the XML document - <br/>1. By using the XML File in Input Stream and using ReadLine method,  I tried to fetch the Tot Node of the payload. But I could not proceed further to count the number of ZoneTot nodes in the payload. <br/>2. I tried to parse the XML using DOM Parser and I got the count of the ZoneTot node under Tot node but I didn't know how to proceed with the next steps of splitting the node. I will paste both the codes in my next comments.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie,<br/> This is the first time I am posting something on Java community and I wanted to be clear what my requirement was. I apologize in case the long XML texts bothers you. I wish to split the Tot node into two in case more than one ZoneTot node appears under Tot node. Each Tot node should have only one ZoneTot node.

Comment: @Taylor, <br/> I am unable to post my code as it says text too long. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: You can't paste the code in comments, try editing your question.  If that's still too long, you can edit down the xml to the relevant bits or use pastebin.